# inheritance with bundles changes the routes?

Tags: symfony, inheritance, bundle

I have just created a new bundle and its route : it works fine.
Now I would like this bundle to inherit from another bundle I have : I add this method to the bundle class :

```
public function getParent() {
    return 'DemoAsseticGestionRessourcesBundle';
}
```

and suddenly Symfony does not recognize the route and says that it does not exist anymore (the same route).In fact it uses the parent route to go to the new bundle I created and so I cannot use the parent bundle anymore.

Why ?

How should I do ?

(I would like to keep the routes to their owner.)

Note : I use yml

Thanks to you all

Note2:  my routes

```
demo_gestion_bundle_homepage             ANY    ANY    ANY  /GestionBundle/
demo_assetic_gestion_ressources_homepage ANY    ANY    ANY  /AsseticGestionRessources/
```

So to be clear : when I do /GestionBundle it does not work anymore and when I do /AsseticGestionRessources it leads to the GestionBundle

Answer (score 0):

Check your routing.yml file paths. If these have the same paths, you overwrite the parents routing.yml file.

So if your parentBundle has the routing.yml file located at `src/ParentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` and the childBundle has the routing.yml file located at `src/ChildBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`, it's not gonna work.

It's nice if you post your app/console router:debug output here

Comment: Ok, that looks OK. So, if you go to /GestionBundle/ it says "Route not found" ? Is this in the dev or prod env and did you try to clear te cache ?